# Add custom venues/events for certain locations on google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to add own venues and respective events to Google Maps, if so - what way and what API's would you recommend for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#adding_a_place